# Deploying dhcp-server on router: is netplan involved?

Tags: dhcp-server, netplan

I have a PC that acts as my home router.

- It has a NIC to the WAN.
- It has a NIC to the LAN.
- It has a NIC to the WAP.

It also has a bridge that spans the LAN/WAP.

Now, I want this router to dispense all the IP addresses as the DHCP server.

What I don't know is: **is netplan in any way involved with adding dhcp-server?** Or does dhcp-servicing happen completely outside netplan?

My current netplan config:

```
# Bridge config
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    # WAN port
    eno2:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
    # LAN port to switch
    enx00242788156c:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
    # LAN port to WAP
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces:
        - enx00242788156c
        - eno1
      addresses:
        - 10.1.0.1/22
        - 10.2.0.1/22
```

Lastly, I also want to manually tie MAC addresses I have on my LAN to a hard-coded IP.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of but mostly no.

Netplan specifically is a frontend for systemd-networkd. The latter does have a very minimal DHCP server built-in (intended for containers) as well as IPv6 Router Advertisement support, so *in theory* it is something that might possible to configure via Netplan as well (if it has these networkd settings mapped).

But in general – no, serving DHCP/RA *isn't* the job of an interface configuration tool and it's more common to use separate software for that, which does not interact with Netplan's interface configuration at all (except for requiring a static IPv4 address). Common choices are Dnsmasq (does both) or ISC dhcpd (now unfortunately EOL) or Kea, plus radvd for IPv6 RAs.